# here i am trying to achieve infinite scrolling but what happens when i am scrolling too fast it fire multiple ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

here i am trying to achieve infinite scrolling but what happens when i am scrolling too fast it fire multiple ajax request with same parameter , which cause same data again n again. i have doubt in scroll function of scrollpagination.js here i am giving  you whole content so if any body can help me pls.

```
  index.php
  `<?php $actual_row_count = 400; ?>
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="Stylesheet" />  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollpagination.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                var actual_count = "<?php echo $actual_row_count; ?>";
                $('#quepanel').scrollPagination({
                    'contentPage': 'loadmore.php', // the url you are fetching the results
                    'contentData': {},// { AlbumName: "Dirty Deeds", Entered: "5/1/2012" },// these are the variables you can pass to the request, for example: children().size() to know which page you are
                    'scrollTarget': $(window), // who gonna scroll? in this example, the full window
                    'heightOffset': 10, // it gonna request when scroll is 10 pixels before the page ends
                    'beforeLoad': function(){ // before load function, you can display a preloader div
                        $('#loadMore').fadeIn();                                            
                    },
                    'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){ // after loading content, you can use this function to animate your new elements
                         $('#loadMore').fadeOut();

                         //var i = 0;
                         //$(elementsLoaded).fadeIn(1000);
                        if ($('#quepanel').children().size() > actual_count ){ // if more than 100 results already loaded, then stop pagination (only for testing)
                            $('#loadMoreComments').fadeIn();
                            $('#quepanel').stopScrollPagination();
                         }
                    }
                });

                // code for fade in element by element
                $.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
                    var delay = 0;
                    return this.each(function(){
                        $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
                        delay += 100;
                    });
                };

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "maindiv">
            <div id = "quepanel" class = "middle">

                <?php
                    $qno = 0;
                    $limit = 30;                    
                    for($i=0 ; $i< $limit ; $i++)
                    { ?><div><span class = "srno"><?php echo ++$qno ;?></span><span><?php echo 'hello'.microtime() ;?></span></div> 
                <?php }?>
            </div>
        <div id = "loadMore"  class = "loadmorediv">
            <center><img src = "https://www.google.com/images/loading.gif" /></center>
        </div>
        <div id = "loadMoreComments"  class = "loadmorediv">
            <center><span>No More Records</span></center>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

`
loadmore.php
`<?php

$requested_page = $_GET['iteration'];
$limit = 20;
$from = (($requested_page - 1) * $limit);
$qno = $from ;

            for($i=0 ; $i< $limit ; $i++)
            { ?>
                <div><span class = "srno"><?php echo ++$qno ;?></span><span><?php echo 'hello'.microtime() ;?></span></div> 
        <?php }?>
`
scrollpagination.js


 (function( $ ){
     $.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {

        var opts = $.extend($.fn.scrollPagination.defaults, options);  
        var target = opts.scrollTarget;
        if (target == null){
            target = obj; 
        }
        opts.scrollTarget = target;

        return this.each(function() {
          $.fn.scrollPagination.init($(this), opts);
        });

  };

  $.fn.stopScrollPagination = function(){
      return this.each(function() {
        $(this).attr('scrollPagination', 'disabled');
      });

  };

  var itr = 2;
  $.fn.scrollPagination.loadContent = function(obj, opts){
     var target = opts.scrollTarget;
     var mayLoadContent = $(target).scrollTop()+opts.heightOffset >= $(document).height() - $(target).height();
     if (mayLoadContent){
         if (opts.beforeLoad != null){
            opts.beforeLoad(); 
         }

         $(obj).children().attr('rel', 'loaded');
         $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: opts.contentPage+"?iteration="+itr,
              data: opts.contentData,
              success: function(data){
                itr++;
                $(obj).append(data); 
                var objectsRendered = $(obj).children('[rel!=loaded]');

                if (opts.afterLoad != null){
                    opts.afterLoad(objectsRendered);    
                }
              }
         });
     }

  };

  $.fn.scrollPagination.init = function(obj, opts){
     var target = opts.scrollTarget;
     $(obj).attr('scrollPagination', 'enabled');

     $(target).scroll(function(event){
        if ($(obj).attr('scrollPagination') == 'enabled'){
                $.fn.scrollPagination.loadContent(obj, opts);
                //alert(event.isPropagationStopped());
        }           
            //event.stopPropagation();
            //console.log(event.isPropagationStopped());
            event.preventDefault();
     });

     //$.fn.scrollPagination.loadContent(obj, opts);

 };

 $.fn.scrollPagination.defaults = {
         'contentPage' : null,
         'contentData' : {},
         'beforeLoad': null,
         'afterLoad': null  ,
         'scrollTarget': null,
         'heightOffset': 0        
 }; 
})( jQuery );`
style.css
`@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

    body{

            font-family:Segoe UI Light,Segoe UI,Tahoma,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            color: #C76A6A;
            color: #0099D2;
            color : black ;
        }

    #loadMoreComments{

        background-color : white;
        font-weight: bold;
        color : black;
        border : solid 1px gray;
        padding : 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
        border-radius: 1px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4+, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
        width : 500px;
        margin : 10px auto;
        display : none;     
    }
    #loadMore{

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display:none;
        z-index:2;
    }

    #quepanel{

        padding-top : 10px;
        margin-left : auto;
        margin-right : auto ;
        width: 600px;
    }

    .maindiv{

        width: 960px;
        height: auto;
        border : red 2px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color: #F8F8F8;
        padding : 1px 10px 10px 10px ;
    }


    .middle{

        margin-right : auto;
        margin-left : auto;
    }


    .srno{

        width  : 30px;
        display : inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-border-radius: 45px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
        border-radius: 45px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4+, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
        background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
        color: #15CFA3;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding : 5px 0 ;
        color : white;
        border :  1px gray;
        margin-top: 5px;

    }   
    `
```

Comment: When I read "here i am" all I could think about was "ROCK you like a hurricane!"

Comment: I'm not going to read all that code, but this is what I would suggest: as soon as the user scrolls to the bottom, you initiate an AJAX request to grab more data (and of course, display a "loading" image or something). You also set a boolean in some way to true, to say the AJAX is processing. On complete of the AJAX call, you set this boolean to false, to say there is nothing processing. Every time you make an AJAX call for this infinite scrolling stuff, check the boolean first - if it's `true`, the means something's being processed...so don't even bother making the AJAX call.

Comment: if ($(obj).attr('scrollPagination') == 'enabled'){
                $.fn.scrollPagination.loadContent(obj, opts);
            }           
            //event.stopPropagation();
              event.preventDefault();

Comment: damn big code! not going to read

Comment: i am confused with event.stopPropagation() method

Comment: @jaipsah : sorry but here i am trying to give u a whole working code it works fine 99% cases , my intension is to help others with better solution. thanx for ur time.

Comment: use a boolean value lik ementionned to prevent multiple ajax request.
but alos use an array to store the data when someone click something, so when your request is proceessed, you can pop it from the array and move on to the next one...

Comment: have you got any solution !??? please let me know if you got !

Answer (score 0):

How about using async: false in your ajax call .. The AJAX call in your loadcontent would be --

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: opts.contentPage+"?iteration="+itr,
              data: opts.contentData,
              async: false,
              success: function(data){
                itr++;
                $(obj).append(data); 
                var objectsRendered = $(obj).children('[rel!=loaded]');

                if (opts.afterLoad != null){
                    opts.afterLoad(objectsRendered);    
                }
              }
         });
```